# Perl, how to merge data with duplicate identifier and overlapping values into a hash

Tags: perl, hashtable, csv

I was wondering if you could help me with a coding problem which I can't get my head around. The tab-delimited data I have looks like something like the following:

```
00001  AU:137  AU:150  AU:180
00001  AU:137  AU:170
00002  AU:180
00003  AU:147  AU:155
00003  AU:155
```

The output I want is:

```
00001  AU:137  AU:150  AU:180  AU:170
00002  AU:180
00003  AU:147  AU:155
```

So the first column (identifier) will merge the values, removing duplicates, so that it becomes a hash. I'm not sure how to work with my current data because it can't be a hash having duplicate keys. I'm also not sure how to push the data into an array if the identifier is the same.

I apologize for not having a code. I did try a few, actually, quite a lot, but they don't look right even to a newbie like myself.

Any help, suggestions would be greatly appreciated and thank you so much for your time and answer. I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Script:***

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;
sub uniq { return keys %{{map {$_=>1} @_}}; }

open my $fh, '<input.txt' or die $!;
foreach (<$fh>) {
  $hash{$1} .= $2 if /^(\S+)(\s.*?)[\n\r]*$/;
}
close $fh;

foreach (sort keys %hash) {
  my @elements = uniq split /\t/, $hash{$_};
  print "$_\t", join(' ', sort @elements), "\n";
}
```

***Output:***

```
00001    AU:137 AU:150 AU:170 AU:180
00002    AU:180
00003    AU:147 AU:155
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the script. Unfortunately, it's not giving me the results I would like as in, it's also printing duplicate values for each key. Would there be a way to get rid of the duplicates? Thank you.

Comment: @absolutenewbie - My script works well on my computer, with no duplicates. Are you sure you execute my script above?

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I should make this clear. The example output does look the same. I'm just wondering why it's giving me duplicates in a larger set of data I have...Anyway, thank you so much. You got me close enough get rid of duplicate keys. Now I need to find a way to get rid of duplicate values for each key. Thanks again.

Comment: This doesn't produce the output you say it does, since it won't remove duplicate data as the OP requested. There are two occurrences of `AU:137` with a label of `00001` and two of `AU:155` with a label of `00003`, all of which your program leaves in place. You are also splitting the record on a single whitespace character instead of a tab, which would break the program if there was a space character in any of the first fields, although I admit that is highly unlikely!

Comment: @stackoverflow: the OP means duplicates in the *values*, not in the keys.

Comment: @Borodin - I tested my script again and its results are as asked by OP. First loop merges values with same keys, second loop removes duplicates. And OP's input file does not have tabs, so code is for his input. If he change input, then code need be changed, but he didn't.

Comment: @stackoverflow: OK the reason your program isn't working is because you are splitting the values on a single space character. The OP's data *is* tab-separated, which is why both he and I commented that your solution prints duplicate values. This program works only with spaces between the values in the source data.

Comment: @Borodin - I don't understand you previous edit then, but regardless of that - why you believe his input contains tabs? The best way would be actually to use /\s+/ I believe...

Comment: @stackoverflow: because he says *The tab-delimited data I have...*. Splitting on `/\s+/` would break up any fields that contained spaces, which may exist even though there are none in the sample data.

Comment: @Borodin - I overlook that. Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

I hope this gives some idea to solve your problem:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash = ();

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my (@row) = split(/\s+/);
    my $firstkey = shift @row;

    foreach my $secondkey (@row) {
            $hash{$firstkey}{$secondkey}++;
    }
}

print Dumper \%hash;

__DATA__
00001  AU:137  AU:150  AU:180
00001  AU:137  AU:170
00002  AU:180
00003  AU:147  AU:155
00003  AU:15
```

Comment: `my %hash = ();` is redundant.  Just say `my %hash;`.  That also protects you from writing `my %hash = {};` by accident.  Also, for tab-delimited data, you should split on `/\t/` (or possibly `/\t+/` if you want to ignore blank fields).

Comment: `my %hash = ()` reinitializes hash while `my %hash` just defines scope. I prefer always make variables clear if i don't want data in them being available during multiple calls (closures). About `tab` i overread, so, yes `\t` is much cleaner.

Comment: `my` *always* creates a new, empty variable that has no connection to previous calls. (`our` doesn't, because it deals with globals.)

Comment: Hi cjm, wk, thank you so much for your help. Unfortunately, the script is not working. I am only getting '$VAR1 = {};' without errors. Would you be able to give me any suggestions?

Comment: @absolutenewbie: do you use my script exacty as it is above or you made some modifications? In my DATA-block is no tabs (just spaces), so it should use `/\s+/` on split.

Comment: I like saying `my %hash = ();` sometimes, especially if I'm initializing other things around it. It is unnecessary, but I also think of it as yelling "A NEW HASH LOL NO RLY K THX!!!!!", which is sometime necessary to emphasize the point. :)

Answer (score 3):

The classical solution to this uses a hash; in fact a hash of hashes, as there are duplicate line numbers as well as duplicate values per line.

This program produces the output you need. It expects the data file to be passed on the command line.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data;

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  my ($key, @items) = split /\t/;
  $data{$key}{$_}++ for @items;
}

print join("\t", $_, sort keys %{$data{$_}}), "\n" for sort keys %data;
```

**output**

```
00001 AU:137  AU:150  AU:170  AU:180
00002 AU:180
00003 AU:147  AU:155
```

Or if you prefer a command-line solution

```
perl -aF/\t/ -lne'$k=shift @F; $d{$k}{$_}++ for @F; END{print join "\t", $_, sort keys %{$d{$_}} for sort keys %d}' myfile
```

(It may need a little tweaking as I can only test on Windows at present.)